# googleAPI: URL shortner gives error on request for shorten the longUrl

Tags: google-api, google-url-shortener

Hi i have been using google shortner for a month & have tried shortening urls near about 50 times & were successful. but today when i tried shortening url for the same task, it showed me the error

```
object(stdClass)#9 (1) { 
["error"]=> object(stdClass)#11 (3) { 
["errors"]=>  array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#12 (4) { 
["domain"]=> string(11) "usageLimits" 
["reason"]=> string(23) "dailyLimitExceededUnreg" 
["message"]=> string(76) "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded.         Continued use requires signup." 
["extendedHelp"]=> string(36) "https://code.google.com/apis/console" } 
} 
["code"]=> int(403) 
["message"]=> string(76) "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded.   Continued use requires signup." } 
 }
```

I am not able to understand what it is???
i have signed up already & using shortner service for a month. please help me out with this problem

Comment: same problem here, been using it since November last year

Comment: have you got any solution or another option???...

Answer (score 0):

Google limits service volume for developer who has no API key applied. Just go to developer console, apply your key, and use it in your code.

I found Google url shorter API supports only approximately three to four hundred times re-direct service for ANONYMOUS user. After that, you have to register a developer account via https://console.developers.google.com/, setup correctly, get the specified API key,  and use it in your code.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Well i tried this option you have suggested.... but the registration should be premium then only i can access it.

Comment: I have switched to the bitly url shortner service as google donot shorten request containing localhost:90(my port 80 is used for different service) & ip address.